# How to make irregularly-shaped SVGs overlap while maintaining all areas clickable?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-float

I have created 4 SVGs (all same shapes) that are floated to the left. I have tried to make them overlap (as it looks nicer that way) but the problem is that since their shapes are irregular, some areas become un-clickable.

I used this as the CSS code:

```
.interact-arrow {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100px;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
}
```

This is the complete codepen demo of the problem: http://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/pgvJoa

How do I properly code the CSS so that I can click on any area of the individual arrows? I'm using `<image>` inside the `<svg>` as the clickable area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a clickable grid of triangles using html, svg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001691/how-to-create-a-clickable-grid-of-triangles-using-html-svg)

Comment: you need that the click will not overlap the previous image too?

Comment: Check this.... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbZQWJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to apply CSS classes directly to your SVG.

See the SVG tags need to be sisters

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper-interact-arrow">
    <svg class="interact-arrow button-reverse">
        ...
    </svg>

    <svg class="interact-arrow button-play">
        ...
    </svg>

    <svg class="interact-arrow button-pause">
        ...
    </svg>

    <svg class="interact-arrow button-arrow">
        ...
    </svg>
```

See the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGMmaY